# how to use camera in windows mobile 6 application

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I am creating windows mobile 6.5 application . In that application i have to use camera operations like picture and video.
There is a form which contains two buttons one for picture and other for video. If user click picture button then camera starts and click picture and save picture on a specified location. Same steps are for Video capturing from application

Any help appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is using the [CameraCaptureDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.cameracapturedialog.aspx) on the [Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.aspx), This method is independent of the hardware. See this example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms;

namespace CameraExample
{

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Code Designer.cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private IContainer components;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnPhoto = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnVideo = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.sfdFile = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnPhoto
            // 
            this.btnPhoto.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.btnPhoto.Name = "btnPhoto";
            this.btnPhoto.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 20);
            this.btnPhoto.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnPhoto.Text = "Photo";
            this.btnPhoto.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPhoto_Click);
            // 
            // btnVideo
            // 
            this.btnVideo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 3);
            this.btnVideo.Name = "btnVideo";
            this.btnVideo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 20);
            this.btnVideo.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnVideo.Text = "Video";
            this.btnVideo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnVideo_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 294);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnVideo);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnPhoto);
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private Button btnPhoto;
        private SaveFileDialog sfdFile;
        private Button btnVideo;

        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        enum CameraType
        {
            Photo,
            Video
        }

        private void btnPhoto_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            sfdFile.FileName = "photo.jpg";
            sfdFile.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg";
            if (sfdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                ShowCamera(sfdFile.FileName, CameraType.Photo);
        }

        private void btnVideo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            sfdFile.FileName = "video.wmv";
            sfdFile.Filter = "Video Files |*.wmv";
            if (sfdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                ShowCamera(sfdFile.FileName, CameraType.Video);
        }

        private void ShowCamera(string FileName, CameraType typeOfCamera)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName);
            CameraCaptureDialog camera = new CameraCaptureDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = fi.DirectoryName,
                DefaultFileName = fi.Name,
                Mode = typeOfCamera == CameraType.Photo ? CameraCaptureMode.Still : CameraCaptureMode.VideoWithAudio,
                VideoTypes = CameraCaptureVideoTypes.All,
                Title = "Using the camera"
            };

            if (camera.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                MessageBox.Show((typeOfCamera == CameraType.Photo ? "Photo " : "Video ") + FileName + " Captured");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not Captured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SHCameraCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb160743.aspx) function.  It can do exactly as you specify: save a video or image file to a user defined location all using the built-in Camera application.  It would just take a few moments to make your application using this API.